# Google Maps API gets loaded but stays on page even after going to other webpages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3

I have tried including the google maps api in my rails project.

Here is my destination new.html.erb:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<MY API KEY>" async defer></script>
<div class="container col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
<h1>New Destination</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', destinations_path %>
</div>
```

and here is the destinations index.html.erb page (which is the 'back' link):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Destinations</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row font-weight-bold">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Address
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      Latitude
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      Longitude
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  </div>
  <% @destinations.each do |destination| %>
  <div class="row bottom-border">
          <div class="col-md-4"><%= link_to destination.address, destination %></div>
          <div class="col-md-1"><%= destination.latitude %></div>
          <div class="col-md-1"><%= destination.longitude %></div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="col-xs-2"><%= link_to 'Check in', new_check_in_path(:destination_id => destination) %></div>
              <div class="col-xs-1"><%= link_to 'Delete', destination, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></div>
          </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <br>
  <%= link_to 'New Destination', new_destination_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
</div>
<br>
```

In the index.html.erb, the google maps api is not included. The Google maps api is only included once, in the destination new.html.erb.

When first clicking into index, the google maps api is not loaded. After clicking into new.html.erb the google maps api gets loaded. However, when clicking 'back' into index.html.erb, the google maps api stays on the page. Then when clicking into new.html.erb again, it now shows the error "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."

And so, when clicking back into the destinations page again, the google maps api is loaded twice. I've tried multiple things from other threads to stop the google api from loading twice, like only loading it after window.onload, setting window.google={} after its' been loaded, loading it synchronously, using callback function, but nothing seems to work...

When removing the line `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<MY API KEY>" async defer></script>` from new.html.erb, no more google maps api were loaded on any of the pages.(so this should confirm new.html.erb was the only place where it is being loaded from)

any idea how this google maps api can stop getting loaded?

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: yes, turbo links is included in the project

/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

Comment: also check that you're not using both jquery_ujs and rails_ujs in your application.js file

Comment: Looks like i only have jquery_usj,
This is in my application.js:

`//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
`

Comment: I wonder if it would work if you put it in the head with a content_for block...

Comment: So, I tried this:
`<% content_for :script do %>
<%= javascript_include_tag("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<API KEY>") %>
<% end %>` and then yielded it: `<%= yield :script %>` But it seems to still give the same issue: You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

Comment: @BradWerth: So, I tried removing turbo-links from /app/assets/javascripts/application.js, and this has solved the issue. But this will cause webpages to load slower, right? Would you suggest just to remove turbo-links or is there another solution? Thank you!

Comment: I would keep turbo links, and put the script in the head with a content_for block..